# <a href gets downloaded when in an E-Mail, but in a browser receive HTTP Status 403

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have an email with content type text/html. Withing it, I have a  reference like this:

```
<a href="https://appl04.edireal.com/mediawrapper/servlet/Media?offerId=10690569&amp;offerCode=1595601971823&amp;offerIndex=0" style="color: #DC1C2E">RE/MAX Angebot 2848-1077: PREISREDUKTION! Neues Reihenhaus im Seepark Vösendorf..pdf</a>
```

When I open this email from gmail or another browser-based E-Mail client and click upon the link, the content gets downloaded as a PDF resource.

However, when I paste the href in a browser address bar and try to access it, I receive the message

Status report

description Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.

Any help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersands `&` in the URL have been replaced with the appropriate XML entity `&amp;`.

Therefore, if you want to use that HTML attribute (the `href` value) in a context that isn't XML or HTML (i.e., your address bar), you need to undo this replacement.  So, replace `&amp;` with `&`:

```
https://appl04.edireal.com/mediawrapper/servlet/Media?offerId=10690569&offerCode=1595601971823&offerIndex=0
```